# not getting the mouse scroll property on swf file embedded in an HTML page

Tags: html, flash

I have a flash swf file and I put that into the HTML file.  In the flash swf file, the mouse scroll zoom function is there, but its not functioning when I am inserting that into the HTML page, and if I scroll over the swf area, it also scrolls the html page completely, and it's not functioning at the swf, i.e. the zoom function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this project

http://www.libspark.org/wiki/SWFWheel/en

the mouse wheel a well known problem for the flash player. but the SWFWheel project fixes a lot.